# Where does the program know the exact value of the instance variable if I don't use synchronized in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-threads

I'm learning about Java multithreading and I'm doing some simple tests with synchronized blocks and without synchronized block.

```
public class MultipleMonitorObjects {

    private Object monitor1 = new Object();
    private Object monitor2 = new Object();

    private int counter1 = 0;
//    private int counter2 = 0;

    public void incCounter1() {
//        synchronized (this.monitor1) {
            this.counter1++;
            System.out.println("Inside incCounter1, counter1 = " + counter1);
//        }
    }

    public void incCounter2() {
//        synchronized (this.monitor2) {
            this.counter1++;
            System.out.println("Inside incCounter2, counter1 = " + counter1);
//        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class MultipleMonitorObjectsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultipleMonitorObjects obj = new MultipleMonitorObjects();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                                obj.incCounter1();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 100000; i < 200000; i++) {
                            obj.incCounter2();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why if I comment the synchronized line, the counter is exactly 200000. I understand the case when I'm using synchronized, the counter is 200000, because if there is synchronized block, the value of counter is added in main memory after every incrementation, and it is fetched from main memory before every incrementation, so the program knows the exact value for counter variable at any time. But if I comment the synchronized line, where does the program know the exact value? I thought the value will be different than 200000 at the end.

Comment: the mentioned behavior is not true. If you run the code multiple times, you will not get  200000 in most of the cases. Even if you uncomment the synchronized block ,the answer will not be  200000 as you are putting lock on different object. The answer can only be 200000, if you put lock on a single object. ThreadLocal is the culprit for the above behavior.

Comment: Be aware that the use of `System.out.println` will distort results as that obtains a lock, and thus influences visibility, potentially to the point that it might behave the same as the code using `synchronized` (though that might depend on the platform and other implementation details).

Comment: @GirijaSankarPanda, What you said is not guaranteed to be true. The outcome of running improperly synchronized code is indeterminate: Not guaranteed to be "correct," and not guaranteed to be "incorrect" either.

Comment: @elvis, no surprise that you see the same results with or without `synchronized` because your two threads are `synchronized` on two _different_ objects. Synchronization only means anything if the two threads both synchronize on the _same_ object.

Comment: As @MarkRotteveel said, the printing’s internal synchronization may affect the result. But it’s also possible that starting the second thread is slow enough for the first to finish first. As mentioned by others, synchronizing on different objects can affect the result, while not guaranteeing the intended result. Also “fetched from main memory” is the wrong mindset. That’s not how it works.

Comment: P.S., If you want two threads to do the same thing, you do not need two distinct functions for them to run. They both can run the same function. If you need two threads to do _almost_ the same thing or similar things, then it often makes sense to have them both run the same function, but with different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you are stepping into multithreaded world. Your program shouldn't print 200000 at the end. Please correct your program by adding these lines at the end (after thread2.start() )

```
thread1.join();  //asks main thread to wait until thread1 is finished
thread2.join();  //asks main thread to wait until thread1 is finished
System.out.println(obj.counter1);
```

Now run this program for 3 or 4 times and you will see your program will print different values everytime.

Also, `incCounter1` and `incCounter2` methods should be synchronised on same Object (lets say `monitor1`) if they are updating same `counter1`. If `incCounter1` is updating `counter1` and `incCounter2` is updating `counter2`, then your way of synchronising `Object1` and `Object2` is correct.